# FIX signature for Coinbase PRO API with .NET Core 3.1, C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, coinbase-api

I'm not able to sign correctly to the Coinbase Pro FIX API. This code was working fine till some months ago(i haven't used it for a while). I have read another time the docs to search for some changes and I have found that the sending time must be as a Unix Timestamp in seconds, previously I was using the DateTime in the FIX Format. I have tried to change this but continue to not works, following I will show the code I use to create the signature

```
private string CreateAccessSign(
            char msgType,
            string msgSeqNumber,
            string senderCompId,
            string targetCompId,
            string password
        )
    {
        var sendingTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        var stringToHash = string.Join('\x0001', sendingTime, msgType, msgSeqNumber, senderCompId, targetCompId, password);
        var privateApiKeyAsByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(_privateApiKey);
        using var hmac = new HMACSHA256(privateApiKeyAsByteArray);
        var signature = hmac.ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(stringToHash));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    }
```

The response from their FIX server is "invalid signature" in the corresponding FIX TAG. Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the correct format of the timestamp to use is

`DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.fff")`

but the problem is that the timestamp for the tag 52 is calculated in a separate code location, must be the same in the signature so `var sendingTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();` must be shared among the signature and tag 52